# Past tense of "Seems like everything I've been doing recently is to follow people around."

Tags: grammar, past-tense, backshifting

I tried this:

> **Seemed** like everything **I'd** been doing recently **was** to follow people around.

Is that correct?

Comment: Please see the edit to my answer (added some clarity) if you haven't already.

Comment: Yes, that version (in the body of your post) does seem to be a reasonable past-tense version of the one in the title. :)

Answer (score 3):

No, but I think you may well hear it said like that.

Let's switch up the order of the sentence:

> Following people around seemed like everything I'd been doing recently.

In this order, we must use **following** since the verb is the subject of the sentence.

Likewise, imagine we respond to the question "What have you been doing recently?", we would simply say

> Following people around.

Certainly not "to follow people around".

So, you should say:

> Seemed like *all* I'd been doing recently was **following** people around.

Lastly, I would say "everything" doesn't sound great here. I'd be much more comfortable with "all".